# Как вернуть значение из анонимной функции в callback вызове

Tags: javascript

Есть ajax запрос, как получить из него результат и присвоить его переменной queryResult, затем переменная queryResult должна проверится и если в ее значении что то не так то нужно выйти из addPartition() :

```
function addPartition(){
    var queryResult;
    $.post('controllers/handlerPartition.php',
        {'isExistPartition': true, 'partitionName':   $('#modal_win1_partition_name').val()},
        function (result) {
            return result; //Как получить это значение из вне?
        }
     );
        if (queryResult === 'false') return;
}
```

Пробовал так:

```
function addPartition(){
    var queryResult;
    $.post('controllers/handlerPartition.php',
        {'isExistPartition': true, 'partitionName':   $('#modal_win1_partition_name').val()},
        function (result) {
            queryResult = result; //Присвоение внешней переменой 
        }
    );
   alert(typeof queryResult); //undefined
   if (queryResult === 'false') return;
}
```

Но значение queryResult не определенно. Я так понимаю это из за асинхронности?

Comment: да, это из-за асинхронности.

Comment: А как значение тогда получить?

Comment: Последовательность событий такова, что `result` не будет присвоен `queryResult` до того, как вызовется функция `function (result) { ... }`. Используйте `queryResult` внутри callback'a.

Comment: Мне нужно при определенном значении result в ajax запросе выйти из  внешней функции addPartition()

Comment: Хм, давайте еще раз. К моменту выполнения функции `function (result) { ... }`, функция `addPartition(){ ... }` давно отработает.

Comment: т. е. вы хотите сказать что addPartition() может завершиться раньше чем выполнится  function (result) { ... } ?

Comment: не "может завершиться", a "точно завершится"

Comment: спасибо, теперь все понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) - его и нужно вернуть из вашей функции.

В вашем случае jQuery предоставляет свою версию:

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
  alert( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
  alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

на одно обещание можно подписаться несколько раз:

```
jqxhr.always(function() {
  alert( "second finished" );
});
```

Также обратите внимание на [одну](http://reactivex.io/) из [реализаций](https://github.com/paldepind/flyd) потоков.

Статья о [функциональном программировании в разработке интерфейсов](http://blog.reactandbethankful.com/posts/2015/09/15/understanding-the-functional-revolution/).